# how can I read spss data into R?

Tags: r, spss

I have got a spss dataset which ends with .sps, not spss, now I'm trying to read it into R, I used    read.table, but it doesn't work,    read.spss doesn't work either. I'm thankful for any help! 
I tried

```
read.spss("//Users//Weights//weights_merge.sps")
```

it says this file

> "is not in any supported SPSS format"

Comment: `help.search("spss")`?

Comment: The phrase "doesn't work" does not help us to help you.  See `fortune(324)`.

Comment: Open it in a text editor and see what it looks like.

Comment: welcome to SO :)  `.sps` files are generally spss _syntax_ not spss _data_.  spss software stores data in `.sav` files, which is what the R function `read.spss` needs

Answer (score 0):

.csv - format is suggested.

.csv is more flexible in R.

and in SPSS you can change raw data into .csv